# Change textView while moving finger across buttons

Tags: android, textview, android-button

In my app, I have an activity in which there are 9 buttons and 1 `textView`. I am making use of `OnTouchListener` to change the text in the `textView` as I move my finger accross the buttons.

This is what my activity looks like:
[image]

Here is my **java** code:

```
    button1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            textView.setText("Button 1");
            return false;
        }
    });
    button2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            textView.setText("Button 2");
            return false;
        }
    });
    button3.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            textView.setText("Button 3");
            return false;
        }
    });
    button4.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            textView.setText("Button 4");
            return false;
        }
    });
    button5.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            textView.setText("Button 5");
            return false;
        }
    });
    button6.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            textView.setText("Button 6");
            return false;
        }
    });
    button7.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            textView.setText("Button 7");
            return false;
        }
    });
    button8.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            textView.setText("Button 8");
            return false;
        }
    });
    button9.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            textView.setText("Button 9");
            return false;
        }
    });
```

But the problem with this code is that it only gets the `OnTouchListener` of the first button I touched. In simple words, when i move my finger, the button that I touched first changes the `textView` while the rest of the buttons don't.
 I searched on the net and stackoverflow as well and I came across something like `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` but I don't know how to use it and I am not sure if it is applicable in this case. 
Please help me solve this problem! thank you for your time.

Comment: as a side note, should they all not say `return true;`

Comment: @Doomsknight I am not experienced in android development. Can you please explain what difference will it make?

Comment: The on touch listeners are supposed to return true or false, depending on whether they "consume" the event. Which they do. I don't think it makes any difference though to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work in Android. If underlying View doesn't consume first event (ACTION_DOWN) by returning true, any other events that occur outside of it will be handled by parent View only. If it consume event - all events until ACTION_UP and it itself will be delivered to this View.

If you want to implement such behavior, you need to process all events within a single View, or override dispatchTouchEvent method of parent View to define your own behavior in that case.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please explain your solution with an example?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a switch case :

```
//
button1.setOnTouchListener(this);
button2.setOnTouchListener(this);
button3.setOnTouchListener(this);
button4.setOnTouchListener(this);
button5.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

 @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
switch(v.getID())
{
case(R.id.btn1):
{
 textView.setText("Button 1");
 break;

}
case(R.id.btn2):
{
 textView.setText("Button 2");
 break;
}
case(R.id.btn3):
{
 textView.setText("Button 3");
break;
}
case(R.id.btn4):
{
 textView.setText("Button4");
break;
}
case(R.id.btn5):
{
 textView.setText("Button 5");
break;

default: // bla
}          

return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `setOnClickListener` or switch case for doing whatever you want
either you can `implements OnTouchListener` on your activity and use ACTION_UP

i am doing a first method  for you here

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
             textView.setText("Button 1");          

        }
    });

button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
             textView.setText("Button 2");          

        }
    });
```

you can continue with this ...